# VBA format cells to General

Tags: excel, number-formatting, vba

I would like to format an Excel file to "General", but it's not working for all cells (some are custom, percentage...).

Here is my code:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(LineIndex, 1)
    .Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strLine)
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    'DEFINE THE OPERATION FULLY!!!!
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                   TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                   Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
                   Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
End With
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to format **all** cells to *General*, then use something like:

```
Sub dural()
    ActiveSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"
End Sub
```