# Excel Vba. Convert [m] format to general

Tags: excel, vba

I have this piece of data in Excel that is 1:30. As I want to show the time elapsed in minutes, I define the cell format as [m], to get 90 as my display value. (Cell.Numberformat = [m])

Is there any way to convert this value to "general" format? I still want to have the value 90 in my cell but with "general" format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA format cells to General](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907606/vba-format-cells-to-general)

Comment: I do not agree that this is a duplicate of "VBA format cells to General".  The OP wants to convert a time to a number of minutes which is a lot more than changing the number format.  It would perhaps be legitimate to close the question as unclear.

Comment: OP states he changes `NumberFormat` of cell, but then asks `Is there any way to convert this value to "general" format? I still want to have the value 90 in my cell but with "general" format.` - that was the reason for the dupe flag. Happy to change it but it seems like a dupe (not a bad question at all).

Comment: @RobinMackenzie  This question is not worth arguing over.  My interpretation is the OP wants the display of time values to be in minutes but without having a special number format.  Changing the number format to General will change the display to .0625 which is not what the OP wants.  That is why I do not see this as a duplicate.  I see no way of achieving the OP's objective without change the cell values. There are at least two approaches that might achieve the OP's objective but there is not enough information to determine which approach, if either, would be most appropriate. ,,,

Comment: ...  That why I viewed this as an unclear question.  If you have a different interpretation, I would be pleased to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert your value of 90 minutes to 'General', excel will return a value of '0.0625'.

Try using Application.Text to store your display value of 90 as a variable.

```
myValue = CDbl(Application.Text(myValue, "[m]"))
```

After testing this on a value of 01:30:00, ('hh:mm:ss'), a value of 90 was returned.

Answer (score -1):

Excel stores dates and times as numbers.  Enter “1:30” in one cell and then “.062500” in another.  Reformat the “1:30” cell as “number with six decimal places” and it will display as “.062500.  Reformat the “.062500” cell as “h:mm” and it will display as “1:30”.

When you type into Excel it looks at the value and decides what sort of value it is.  If it decides it is a date or a time or a date and time, it converts it to a number but sets the NumberFormat to match the format of the value.

The integer part of that number is: Days since 1/1/1900”

The fraction part of that number is Seconds since midnight / (24 * 60 * 60)

To display a time in minutes with a number format of "General ", you will need to place a formula in another cell with the value “=HOUR(xn)*60 + MINUTE(xn)” where xn is the address of cell you wish to convert.

Alternatively, a VBA macro could look for cells with a format of “hh:mm”, replace the cell’s value with the number of minutes and replace the NumberFormat with “General”